# Index of the row with most non-zero elements

Tags: code-golf, matrix

**This is a simple one:** Take a matrix of integers as input, and output the index of the row with the most non-zero elements. You may assume that there will only be one row with the most non-zero elements.

#### Test cases:

These are 1-indexed, you may choose if you want 0 or 1-indexed.

```
1
0
row = 1
---
0  -1
0   0
row = 1
---
1   1   0   0   0
0   0   5   0   0
2   3   0   0   0
0   5   6   2   2
row = 4
---
0   4   1   0
0   0  -6   0
0   1   4  -3
2   0   0   8
0   0   0   0
row = 3
```

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
!gs&X>
```

Input is a matrix, with `;` as row separator.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/XzG9WC3C7v//aEMFQwUDELQGU6YQppGCMULUVMEMKGAUCwA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8F8xvVgtwu6/S8j/aENrBYNYrmgDBV0QC8w2VDAEsRQMwAIKphCmkYIxQtRUwQwoYATWaAJSDlGqawZhGQIFdY1BekCiFhBJkOEA).

#### Explanation

```
!     % Transpose
g     % Logical: convert non-zeros to 1
s     % Sum of each column, or sum of row if there's a single row
&X>   % Arg max. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 23 bytes

```
Ordering[Count@0/@#,1]&
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 31 bytes

```r
pryr::f(which.min(rowSums(!m)))
```

returns an anonymous function which takes a matrix:

```r
function(m)which.min(rowSums(!m))
```

`rowSums` sums the rows, with `!m` transforming 0 to 1 and everything else to 0. `which.min` returns the 1-based index of the first row which contains the min sum (i.e., which row has the fewest zeros).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jV7M8IzM5Qy83M0@jKL88uDS3WEMxV1Pzf5pGbmJJUWaFRrKGgY6Bjq6hjoGmjpGOEVAKAA)

Comment: You need `which.min()` since non-zero elements will become FALSE with `!m`.

Comment: @user2390246 oh, wow, I completely misread the question. Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
ΣĀO}θk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3OIjDf6153Zk//8fHW2oowBEBhAUq6MQDWGaIgSMdBSM0VUApc10FIAyRrGxAA/f3S0oY4CEBlAUKyOQjSEaYoQMNJRMEZXAZQ201EAyhjFxgIA)

-2 Bytes thanks to [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer)

#### Explanation

```
ΣĀO}θk
Σ  }   # Sort input by following code
 Ā      # Is element not 0? (vectorized)
  O     # Sum
    θk # Get index of "largest" element
       # Implicit print
```

Comment: Use `Ā` instead of `Ä0›` for -2.

Comment: Yee just realized there is probably a better way to do that part than what I had. Damn I feel like I'm learning a new 05AB1E command every day ^^

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>46</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
snd.minimum.(`zip`[1..]).map(filter(==0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcnLCsMgEIXhV5lFFgqTQZtQuvFJRIjQSIc4Irls@vLWQjibj/984rGtObeW3FHeJFxYLiG1fLku3hIFTRKrSpzPdVfOGa2bRC7goO5cThgggfcGZ7RoAnYZHJ83bc/j1PnAf3/df18I0H4)

How it works

```
    map                    -- for each row
        (filter(==0))      -- collect the 0s
    (`zip`[1..])           -- pair with row index  (<#0s>, <index>)
  minimum                  -- find the minimum
snd                        -- extract index from pair
```

Comment: Nice! Better than mine, good to learn something.

Answer (score 4):

## C#, 69 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;m=>m.IndexOf(m.OrderBy(r=>r.Count(n=>n!=0)).Last())
```

Takes a `List<int[]>` as input and returns the 0-indexed result.

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3, <s>54</s> 48 bytes

```python
lambda a:a.index(min(a,key=lambda r:r.count(0)))
```

Shaved off 6 bytes. Old solution:

```python
lambda a:min(range(len(a)),key=lambda i:a[i].count(0))
```

Comment: Just noticed it matches directly with the changes to the python 2 answer now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 9 bytes

```
0@♀cñ♂RmN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/A4dHMhuTDGx/NbArK9fv/P9pQx1DHAARjdaJBtCmUbaRjjCRuqmOmY6RjFAsA)

Explanation:

```
0@♀cñ♂RmN
0@♀c       count zeroes in each row
    ñ♂R    enumerate and reverse each row (each row becomes [count, index] pair)
       m   minimum
        N  last element (the index)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 bytes

```apl
(⊢⍳⌈/)+/0≠⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdN7@45L/Go65Fj3o3P@rp0NfU1jd41LngUd9UkOx/BTAAKeJ61LvKUMGAC1mkbaKGgYLCofWGmiBawUATXdYQyAFhAxiGKgRiU4SQEZAyxlQFUmEGxCBpI00sFiuYwIyHG3tovRmCbwhRcmi9McQOmPkWCFdArAMA)

`0≠⎕` Boolean matrix where non-zero

`+/` sum rows

`(` apply the following tacit function to the list of sums

`⌈/` the maximum's

`⍳` index

`⊢` in the argument list

`)`

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 17 bytes

```
{{∋0}ᶜ}ᵐA;.∋₎~⌋A∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v7r6UUe3Qe3DbXNqH26d4GitB@Q@auqre9TT7fioY/n//9HRhjqGOgYgGKsTDaJNoWwjHWMkcVMdMx0jHaPY2P9RAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
TL$€M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/ER@VR0xrf////R0cb6hjqGIBgrE40iDaFso10jJHETXXMdIx0jGJjAQ)

1-indexed.

So many 5-byte versions...

`TL$€M`, `T€L€M`, `TJ$€M`, `T€J€M`, `¬¬Ṣ€M`, `ṠAṢ€M`, `ṠAS€M`, `AṠṢ€M`, `AṠS€M`, `¬ċ€0M`, ...

Comment: Why do they all look like words?

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 64 bytes

This one works also with negative numbers in the input, luckily the same length as the original:

```
#(nth(sort-by(fn[i](count(filter #{0}(% i))))(range(count %)))0)
```

Original:

```
#(last(sort-by(fn[i](count(filter pos?(% i))))(range(count %))))
```

Comment: numbers in matrix are integers. so `pos?` isn't correct

Comment: True, I forgot to account for negative integers. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
€ĀOZk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UdOaIw3@Udn//0dHG@oY6hiAYKxONIg2hbKNdIyRxE11zHSMdIxiYwE)

0-indexed.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell - <s>69</s> 68 Bytes

*Saved one byte thanks to Siracusa!*

Rows are zero indexed

```
g=filter
m y=head$g((==maximum y).(y!!))[0..]
f=m.map(length.g(0/=))
```

### Usage

```
f [[1,1,0,0,0],[2,3,0,0,0],[0,5,6,2,2],[1,1,1,1,1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BDoMgEEX3noImLiAZKWg13XASwoJERFKwRm3i7WmxLJq2mc3Pe/l/Rr3ejPcxWjE4v5mlCGhfxWh0X1qMhQh6d@GRIKF4X08nQiSjVBWDCDToGXsz2W2kFrOzICQG7SYkUH8vEJoXN22oRAOSkiuQTKkvyqA6BPwqDhxYureHNucamg/eQgc11H@GL6mfu1WXI3/hqjlWEr9mf/yPTw)

Comment: Defining `g=filter` saves you one byte

Comment: You can even remove a few bytes more with `m y=length$takeWhile(<maximum y)y` and shortening `length` instead of `filter`

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
{0fe=_:e<#}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/2iAt1TbeKtVGufZ/XWpKrPX/6GhDBUMFAxCMVYgG0aZQtpGCMZK4qYKZgpGCUWwsAA)

-2 thanks to [Challenger5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61384/challenger5).

Comment: 11: `{0fe=_:e>#}`

Comment: @Challenger5 `>` should be `<` instead...thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 2):

## q/kdb+, <s>25</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

**Solution:**

```
(*)(<)sum(+)0=/:
```

**Example:**

```
q)(*)(<)sum(+)0=/:enlist(1;0)
0
q)(*)(<)sum(+)0=/:(0 -1;0 0)
0
q)(*)(<)sum(+)0=/:(1 1 0 0 0;0 0 5 0 0;2 3 0 0 0;0 5 6 2 2)
3
q)(*)(<)sum(+)0=/:(0 4 1 0;0 0 -6 0;0 1 4 -3;2 0 0 8;0 0 0 0)
2
```

**Explanation:**

```
first iasc sum flip 0=/:  / ungolfed
                      /:  / each right, apply a function to each item to the right
                    0=    / returns boolean 1b or 0b if item in each list is equal to zero
               flip       / flip (rotate) the output
           sum            / sum these up
      iasc                / return indices if we were to sort ascending
first                     / take the first one
```

**Notes:**

<s>The problem is fairly straightforward, this solution feels overly complicated.</s> As soon as I hit submit I realised the error of my ways.

**Bonus:**

Here's a k solution that weights in at <s>16</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes - almost exactly the same but 7 bytes shorter due to the fact we don't need brackets when using the k built-ins, and as a result some become shorter than the q keywords (e.g. `+/` for `sum` (would be `(+/)` in q)).

```
*<+/+0=/:
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ċ0$ÞḢi@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9It4HK4XkPdyzKdPj//390tIGOQawOkDQEkoZAMhYA)

```
ċ0$ÞḢi@  Main link
   Þ     Sort by
ċ0$              the number of occurences of 0
    Ḣ    Take the first element
     i@  Index in the original array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62 bytes

```python
lambda m:max(range(len(m)),key=lambda n:len(filter(abs,m[n])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LclBCoAgEEDRq7ScAYNqGXQSczGRluRMYi7y9FbQ6sP7seT9lKG6aa6BeFmp4ZHphkSyWQhWgBHVYcv0bxk/dD5km4CWS7EWg4g1Ji@5caB1p9reqDedMVgf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>64 55 52</s> 48 bytes

- **Thanks to @Rod for shaving 9 bytes!!**: count `0`s and use `min()` instead of `max()`
- @Rod saved yet another 3 bytes: use `input()` instead of `def`
- **@ovs saved 4 bytes**: use of `lambda` and hash-map

```python
lambda x:x.index(min(x,key=lambda n:n.count(0)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqkIvMy8ltUIjNzNPo0InO7XSFiqVZ5Wnl5xfmleiYaCpqfm/oCgzr0QhTSMzr6C0RAMoEB1tqKOgoGCAQhjE6kQjREyRhY1AHGPsqnXBKs1g4kaxsQA)

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqkIvMy8ltUIjNzNPo0InO7XSFiqVZ5Wnl5xfmleiYaCpqfm/oCgzr0QhTSMzr6C0RAMoEB1tqKOgoGCAQhjE6kQjREyRhY1AHGPsqnXBKs1g4kaxsQA)

Comment: Thanks @ovs. I didn't exactly understand how it works though.

Comment: It's more or less the same logic that you had on your answer, [but using `min` with the `key` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18296814/4628067)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 62 bytes

0-indexed. Takes a 2D array as input.

```
a=>(a=a.map(x=>x.filter(y=>y).length)).indexOf(Math.max(...a))
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation for this one? Does `filter` implicitly "filter" zeroes?

Comment: You're supposed to return the index of the row...

Comment: Still trying to golf some more off it, @TheLethalCoder, will be adding a demo and an explanation when I'm done. In the meantime, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for more info on `filter`, keeping in mind that `0` is falsey.

Comment: @Neil: Fixed now.

Comment: @Shaggy I assumed that was the case with `filter` was just making sure.

Comment: You may already be below that score by now, but here's a 61: `a=>a.map((r,i)=>m=r.map(v=>n+=!!v,n=0)&&n>m?(o=i,n):m,m=0)&&o` (not really tested).

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 58 bytes

0-Indexed

```php
<?=array_search(max($a=array_map(array_filter,$_GET)),$a);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKUS7@4aYhsdbahjqGMAgrE6XNEghimMY6RjjCxjqmOmY6RjFBtrzWVvBzTENrGoKLEyvjg1sSg5QyM3sUJDJREqlptYoAFhpWXmlKQW6YAt09TUUUnUtP7/HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 18 bytes

```
òø0
jòÚDuu/"
dGØ¾
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///CmwzsMuLKA1CyX0lJ9ISWuFPfDMw7t@//fQEFBwQSIDYHYgAvEA2JdMzjPECKva8xlBJEDYwuYSggGAA)

Unlike most V answers, this is 0-indexed.

```
00000000: f2f8 300a 6af2 da44 7575 2f12 220a 6447  ..0.j..Duu/.".dG
00000010: d8be                                     ..
```

Not bad for a language with no numeric support! `;P`

I also have discovered that the uppercase variant of the *count* command, that is `Ø`, is horribly broken.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 92 bytes

```python
def f(x):
    for e in x:
        e.sort()
    y=x[:]
    y.sort()
    return x.index(y[-1])
```

First sort each row such that the entrys are `[0,0,..,0,x,x,x]` then sort the whole matrix, so that the last entry in `y` is the row we are looking for. 
The copy `y=x[:]` is necessary, since `.sort()` works inplace, hence we don't know the original index after sorting.

I appreciate any help how to golf this solution further. Most bytes are lost because of the whitespaces in each line. The code itself is only 68 bytes long.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNo0LTiksBCNLyixRSFTLzFCogfBBI1SvOLyrR0AQLVNpWRFvFQpjI4kWpJaVFQG16mXkpqRUaldG6hrGa//8DAA)

Comment: I don't know Python but can't you remove most of the whitespace from this?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Python uses indentation instead of brackets for codeblocks, instead of brackets or keywords (e.g. for .. end).

Comment: Even then python can be golfed a fair amount. The following is equivalent to your original code: `def f(a):b=list(map(sorted,a));return b.index(sorted(b)[-1])`

Comment: [This answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128462/38550) uses a for loop and a function but with no newlines so I assume you can remove a lot of them although it is Python 2 the whitespace restrictions should be similar.

Comment: [Don't works for lists with negative numbers](https://tio.run/##TYuxCsMwDET3foVGCZzQJKRDoF9itEWmXuygumB/vevUHXI33N2DO0p6xbDUuosDh5m2GzS5qCDgA@S@T8n4jpqQfqA8s9241ytXSR9tt9GHXTIWO0xM9VAfEjq0djL3bjb2zPXfZ7Nc@LCaRxszM1H9Ag "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [59 bytes with an equivalent def-function that also handles negative values](https://tio.run/##FcqxCsMgFEbhV3H0wm/Q2HRo6ZOIgyRK71ANYsA@vbXT@YZzftu7ZDvGEZNIstMjvBwve7lyk5pSqYIFZ9H9s8Z21SkXFs5H7PLDWQYiP87K807SOYMVFjcPp/@FmbLYcIeeUgbKQkNt3hONHw)

Comment: Even 56 bytes: `def f(x):k=[i.count(0)for i in x];print(k.index(min(k)))`

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
xQh/D0
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=xQh%2FD0&input=%5B%5B0%2C+4%2C+1%2C+0%5D%2C+%5B0%2C+0%2C+-6%2C+0%5D%2C+%5B0%2C+1%2C+4%2C+-3%5D%2C+%5B2%2C+0%2C+0%2C+8%5D%2C+%5B0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%5D%5D&debug=0)

Instead of finding the row with the most non-zero elements, I find the row with the least zero elements.

`/D0`: Order (`D`) by count (`/`) of zeros (`0`). Implicitly applied to `Q`, the input.

`h`: Take the first, and minimum, element.

`xQ`: Find the index (`x`) in the input (`Q`) of that element.

Comment: This was exactly what I had a well. It felt clunky and like I was missing something, but it seems like there's just not a clean way to do it :(

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 46 bytes

```
%M`\b0
m`(?<=(¶.+)*)$
;$#1
O#`.+
!`(?<=^.+;).+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9f1TchJsmAKzdBw97GVuPQNj1tTS1NFS5rFWVDLn/lBD1tLkWwVJyetrWmnvb//wYKCgomQGwIxAZcIB4Q65rBeYYQeV1jLiOIHBhbwFRCMAA)

0-indexed. Works with positive and negative integers (and 0). Assumes no leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 16 bytes

```
0{[:/:@:+/@|:0=]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WyqA62krfysFKW9@hxsrANvZ/SWpxiYKtlYKpgomCioIBkDQEkiAYbwamDIFC8cYKRmCOBVTOgCs1OSNfAaQZwkoDs/8DAA)

Comment: `0{&\:1#.|@*` for 11: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81Wz6BaLcbKUFmvxkHrf0lqcYmCrZWCqYKJgoqCAZA0BJIgGG8GpgyBQvHGCkZgjgVUzoArNTkjXwGkGcxSV4cIpIGF/gMA "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>119</s> 101 bytes

```java
m->{int i=m.length,M=0,I=0,c;for(;i-->0;){c=0;for(int x:m[i])if(x!=0)c++;if(c>M){M=c;I=i;}}return I;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLPT8IwFMfv/BVPE5JNu2WAGmMtiRcTDpz0RjjU0mFx7Zb2TSHL/nYsGyoyTbRpt9fv@9FPm7firzzKC2lWi5et0kVuEVZei0tUWXxGex0tLY1AlZsfnQ6t5HrnKsqnTAkQGXcOplwZqHoAe9UhR/97zdUCtPcFD2iVWc7mwO3ShbtIgMd8YvB@f9qtMjibz@ZjSIHBVkfjyiugmI4zaZb4TKYsIRO/BE1zG1AVReOEhpVgSSPsotc3eqbmoUqD9QlLQnF@Tr0txtOwmjJBJ0zRurYSS2tgQustNIM2NCgdBikBI99gz9Ji7kY1qMnXJqn3dk0gCf@SnhCIvpfwmf@uMiDgZ9LO42oELruOIYHRbxk@/IqAjxgegIz@ep2LlqVLEV115UETH42O0NqE626No9cZNlB1z38OG6th/K2JyAc26MYEuS6kQLkIob3Iw8ah1HFeYlz43sQ0OO27G@i7vjkld9byjYsXUhaPedu7gQ4JpDEvimxz5/yhXmDss2pLWG/fAQ)

Java, that sweet verbose language :)

Thanks for saving 18 bytes, @KevinCruijssen ;)

Comment: +1 nice answer. Was about to post an even more verbose answer myself.. Was doubting whether to post it, and it's a good thing I hadn't since it's 145 bytes and ugly.. ;) [Here it is...](https://tinyurl.com/ybsa427y) EDIT: Hmm, btw, your last two test cases fail..

Comment: Checking your code just made me realize there's a bug in my answer! o_O I don't even know how my test cases pass...

Comment: Good to go, I fixed it!

Comment: Nice! Btw, you can golf it by using a for-each inner loop to get rid of `j` and other longer parts like `j=m[i].length,` and `m[i][j]` like this: [`m->{int i=m.length,M=0,I=0,c;for(;i-->0;){c=0;for(int x:m[i])if(x!=0)c++;if(c>M){M=c;I=i;}}return I;}`](https://tinyurl.com/ycztjkk9) (**101 bytes**)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 145 bytes

```
import java.util.*;m->{int t=0,s=0,i=0,r=0;for(;i<m.size();i++){List l=(List)m.get(i);for(;l.remove(0L););s=l.size();if(s>t){t=s;r=i;}}return r;}
```

Ugly, but it works..

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##vVPRboIwFH3nK@5jOweCbr50mOzdmSU@LnuoUFwdFNJeXBzh21lBtphFkyUTGy43nJZzz2lvt3zH3bwQahu/NzIrco2wtZhXoky9GwYA4zE8cwvnCeCbgPUehRvlpULHiVJuDDxxqSoHQCoUOuGRgGX72QEQkYU0CBllFqrBvuxjkKOMYAkKwiZz51W7EkP/1tiQNnTosyTXhMmHzDPyUxDK5GhEq44sDTtSmnkbgUTSw9LU0yLLd4L4C8ooM2H682dCzBxphaFhOpSsrrXAUivQrG7YQVJRrlMrqVe2y2UMmfVFVqil2ry8AqcHU6u9QZF5eYleYacwVUR5EVHiAx615vtWGaFVxeP4NBhYeXXd7cffx1k2v2ez0VP@W2BL2Wb38koHUhz01MFRiVMlL2@kzfeDVpv0rNOrevv2NOvz5CgP1G53Jw5xuENzZ4OWCX6ZcqeDNMV1G/3cDa6duvkC)

```
import java.util.*;         // Required import for List

m->{                        // Method with List parameter and integer return-type
  int t=0,s=0,i=0,          //  Temp integers
      r=0;                  //  Result integer
  for(;i<m.size();i++){     //  Loop over the List of Lists
    List l=(List)m.get(i);  //   Get the inner List
    for(;l.remove(0L););    //   Remove all zeros
    s=l.size();             //   Get the size of the List
    if(s>t){                //   If this size is larger than the previous
      t=s;                  //    Set `t` to this size
      r=i;                  //    And set the result to the index of this row
    }
  }                         //  End of loop
  return r;                 //  Return result-integer
}                           // End of method
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 51 Bytes

```
m=>m.reduce((a,e,i)=>e.filter(x=>x).length>a?i:a,0)
```

where `m` is a 2D array and the index returned is 0-indexed

**Test cases:**

```js
f=
m=>m.reduce((a,e,i)=>e.filter(x=>x).length>a?i:a,0)

console.log(f([[1], [0]]))
console.log(f([[0,-1], [0,0]]))
console.log(f([[1,1,0,0,0], [0,0,5,0,0], [2,3,0,0,0], [0,5,6,2,2]]))
console.log(f([[0,4,1,0], [0,0,-6,0], [0,1,4,-3], [2,0,0,8], [0,0,0,0]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes

```python
def f(x,i=0):print i;x[i].remove(0);f(x,-~i%len(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNo0In09ZA06qgKDOvRCHTuiI6M1avKDU3vyxVw0DTGiSvW5epmpOap1Ghqfk/TSMzr6C0RAPIjI421FFQUDBAIQxidaIRIqbIwkYgjjF21bpglWYwcaPYWAA)

This version removes 0s progressively through the arrays, printing the current index, and crashes when there are no more zeros to remove. Last printed index is the answer.

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
lambda x,i=0:0in x[i]>x[i].remove(0)and f(x,-~i%len(x))|i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFCJ9PWwMogM0@hIjoz1g5E6BWl5uaXpWoYaCbmpSikaVTo6NZlquak5mlUaGrWZP4vKMrMKwGKZ@YVlJZoaGr@j4421FFQUDBAIQxidaIRIqbIwkYgjjF21bpglWYwcaPYWAA)

Wanted to try a different approach from what's already here. So here I recursively iterate over the array removing one 0 at a time until the current array no longer has any zeroes - and then output the index of that array.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 100 bytes

```
m->m.indexOf(m.stream().map(z->{z.removeIf(x->x==0);return z;}).max((q,r)->q.size()-r.size()).get())
```

### Explanation

The power of Lists and Streams! (and without the imports, to boot!)

Let's break this little lambda down into chunks:

```
m.stream().map(z->{z.removeIf(x->x==0);return z;}
```

We turn our List of Lists (the matrix in the question) into a Stream and go through each element, removing all of those pesky zeroes from each sub-List. We need to explicitly return the sublist each time here, because `Stream.map()` converts each object in the Stream to whatever the mapping returns, and we don't want to change them.

```
.max((q,r)->q.size()-r.size()).get()
```

We go through our newly de-zeroed sublists, and simply check how big they are next to each other, getting us the biggest sublist. The `.get()` is because the `Stream.max()` returns an Optional, requiring that extra function call.

```
m.indexOf()
```

We take that biggest sublist, and find where it is in the main List, giving us our result!

### Notes

This breaks if the outer list is empty, but I'm taking

> You may assume that there will only be one row with the most non-zero elements.

to imply that there will always be at least one row. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/eTHproductions/japt/), 7 bytes

0-indexed. Takes input as an array of arrays.

```
mè
bUrw
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=begKYlVydw==&input=W1swLDQsMSwwXSxbMCwwLC02LDBdLFswLDEsNCwtM10sWzIsMCwwLDhdLFswLDAsMCwwXV0=)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of array `U`.
`[[0,4,1,0],[0,0,-6,0],[0,1,4,-3],[2,0,0,8],[0,0,0,0]]`

```
mè
```

Map (`m`) over `U` returning the count of truthy (non-zero) elements in each sub-array. Implicitly assign this new array to `U`.
`[2,1,3,2,0]`

```
Urw
```

Reduce (`r`) array `U` by getting the greater of the current value and the current element.
`3`

```
b
```

Get the first index in `U` where the element equals that value and implicitly output the result.
`2`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 34 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.25 bytes

```
vT@ÞM
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwidlRAw55NIiwiIiwiW1swLDQsMSwwXSxbMCwwLC02LDBdLFswLDEsNCwtM10sWzIsMCwwLDhdLFswLDAsMCwwXV0iXQ==)

Bitstring:

```
1000101100100011101101110100011000
```

optimally encoded solution

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⊢⍖/+≠0⍉
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__ZiDihpAg4oqi4o2WLyviiaAw4o2JCgpbWzFdCiBbMF1dCmYKW1swIMKvMV0KIFswIDBdXQpmCltbMSAxIDAgMCAwXQogWzAgMCA1IDAgMF0KIFsyIDMgMCAwIDBdCiBbMCA1IDYgMiAyXV0KZgpbWzAgNCAxIDBdCiBbMCAwIMKvNiAwXQogWzAgMSA0IMKvM10KIFsyIDAgMCA4XQogWzAgMCAwIDBdXQpmCg==)

```
⊢⍖/+≠0⍉
      ⍉  # transpose
    ≠0   # where is it not equal to zero?
  /+     # sum columns
⊢⍖       # index of maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, 25 bytes

```perl
$;[grep$_,@F]=$.}{$\=pop@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/FOjq9KLVAJV7HwS3WVkWvtlolxrYgv8Dh/38DBQUFEyA2BGIDLhAPiHXN4DxDiLyuMZcRRA6MLWAqIfhffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0OD/7oFiQA)